# Why does [imagePickerController setAllowsEditing:YES] substantially reduce the photo resolution from the camera?

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch

I’m using `UIImagePickerController` to take photos through my app. If I use the default

```
[imagePickerController setAllowsEditing:NO];
```

then the resulting photo has the full resolution 2592x1936 (and many megabytes). However, if I turn on editing with

```
[imagePickerController setAllowsEditing:YES];
```

the end photo is only 640x640 (and less than 1 megabyte).

Why is this happening? Any way to get a higher quality for edited photos?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be getting the high resolution image from

```
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info
{
         [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage]
         [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerEditedImage]
.... 
}
```

Comment: Yeah, the edited image for some reason is always small. According to the docs, it will also always be square. Anyway, the default ended up suiting me just fine, so I'm not going to bother with how to get a different edited image out of the camera for now. Thanks.